# Imagick not displaying to page with content headers set

Tags: php, imagick

I am having some trouble getting `getImagesBlob();` to display to page when headers are set.

the code below returns a courrpt image symbol in the browser

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$combined->setImageFormat('jpg');
echo $combined->getImagesBlob();
```

However, if I don't set the content type and display the image within an image tag this works

```
echo "<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($combined->getImagesBlob())."' />";
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Could you give us an example image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had an echo in the code which was causing this error. Deleting the extra echo was the fix.